# PHP MySQL - How to select items randomly on weekly basis?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, random

in PHP MySQL if i want select items randomly on **Daily Basis** i use following code.

```
ORDER BY rand(" . date("Ymd") . ")
```

But How i can select items randomly on **Weekly Basis** ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps to you. you can query for the range of 7 days. here i am also assuming that you are keeping date in some column.

let's say for the first week of Oct 2018 you can use the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE column_name BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-07' ORDER BY RAND()
```

for the second week of Oct 2018

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE column_name BETWEEN '2018-10-08' AND '2018-10-14' ORDER BY RAND()
```

and so on for next weeks.